# There is no user provider for user "App\Entity\User"

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to use FosUserBundle with Symfony 3.4.7, but I get the following error:

> There is no user provider for user "App\Entity\User".

This error happens on the last line of the following code:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$controller->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
$controller->get('session')->set('_security_main',serialize($token));
```

Here is the content of the security.yaml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
    App\Entity\User: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        class: App\Entity\User

    firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Here is the fos_user.yaml file:

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm
  firewall_name: main
  use_listener: false
  user_class: App\Entity\User
  from_email:
      address: lannuzel+bot@gmail.com #"%mailer_user%"
      sender_name: bot #"%mailer_user%"
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
    "php": "^7.0.8",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "symfony/asset": "^3.4",
    "symfony/console": "^3.4",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^3.4",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/form": "^3.4",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^3.4",
    "symfony/lts": "^3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "^3.4",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "^3.4",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/templating": "^3.4",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^3.4",
    "symfony/validator": "^3.4",
    "symfony/web-link": "^3.4",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "*",
    "symfony/yaml": "^3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^3.4",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^3.4",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^3.4",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.4",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^3.4"
    },
    "config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
    },
    "replace": {
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
    },
    "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "id": "01C9QBD7ETMR057HZKBE94RA2A",
        "allow-contrib": false
    },
    "symfony.id": "01C9QAREG207VK8TQR3XP0R4DV"
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does your App\Entity\User implements UserInterface ?

Comment: Yes, it extends FOS\UserBundle\Model\User, which implements UserInterface and GroupableInterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake,I had creating a `config/security.yaml` file, whereas there was already a `config/packages/security.yaml` file.

Putting everything in the latter resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Indent `fos_userbundle` under `providers`, because now it isn't recognised as a parameter for providers. YAML is very picky about it's spaces